# Sixth digit after the decimal point

Tags: number-theory

> Determine the sixth number after the decimal point in the number $(\sqrt{1978} +\lfloor\sqrt{1978}\rfloor)^{20}$

I don't understand in the below how they get $y<\frac{1978-1936}{2 \cdot 44}$. Can someone explain that?

**Book solution:**

Let $x=\{(\sqrt{1978}+[\sqrt{1978}])^{20}\}$, then $x=1-y^{20}, y=\sqrt{1978}-[\sqrt{1978}]$.
Because $44^2=1936, y<\frac{1978-1936}{2 \cdot 44}=\frac{21}{44}<0.5$. Therefore $y^{20}<10^{-6}$ and $x=0.999 999 8\ldots$.

Comment: @Joffan take a look at my edit. Does it seem right?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife thanks, I'm almost convinced :-) - I'll think about it a while.

Comment: The book seems to be saying $x = (a+b)^n$.  Let $y$ be such $x =1 - y^n$.  Then $y = a - b$.  If so $(a - b)^n$ has alternating sign  $1 - (a-b)^n$ will be similar to $(a+b)^n$ with same terms but alternating signs... so I don't get it.

Comment: What exactly is $[\sqrt{1978}]$?  I thought it was supposed to be $\lfloor \sqrt{1978} \rfloor = 44$

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathrm{
y=\{\sqrt{1978}\}=\{\sqrt{44^2+42}\}
}$$
Now suppose
$$\mathrm{
44^2+42=(44+z)^2\\
\implies y=\{44+z\}=\{z\}\cdots(I)
}$$
Also we have $$\mathrm{44^2+42<(44+1)^2\\
\implies 0<z<1}$$
Therefore according to $\mathrm{(I)}$ we have
$$\mathrm{
y=z\\
\implies 44^2+42=(44+y)^2\\
\implies 2\cdot44\cdot y=42-y^2<42\\
\implies y<{42\over2\cdot44}
}$$

> Explanation of the book's solution

$\mathrm{a,b,n}$ are natural numbers and $\mathrm n$ is even $\mathrm{\implies(\sqrt a+b)^n+(\sqrt a-b)^n}$ is also a natural number. To see this expand both terms with using binomial theorem. Therefore if $\mathrm a$ is not a perfect square or $\mathrm{(\sqrt a\pm b)^n}$ is non-integer, we must have 
$$\mathrm{
\{(\sqrt a+b)^n\}+\{(\sqrt a-b)^n\}=1
}$$
In our case $\mathrm{a=1978,b=\lfloor\sqrt{1978}\rfloor,x=\{(\sqrt a+b)^n\},y=(\sqrt a-b)=\{\sqrt a\}}$. Therefore
$$\mathrm{
x+\{y^{20}\}=1
}$$
As $\mathrm{0<y<1\implies0<y^{20}<1},$
$$\mathrm{
\{y^{20}\}=y^{20}\\
\therefore x=1-y^{20}
}$$

Comment: Question: does $\lbrace a+b \rbrace = a+b$, ie is there a reason for having the curly braces?

Comment: @cpiegore Yes because $a+b>1$ and $0<\{a+b\}<1$ and you're correct $\lfloor\sqrt{1978}\rfloor=44$.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is confusing, but you didn't really answer my question.  I'm asking whether $\lbrace a+b \rbrace $ and $a+b$ are different things.

Comment: @cpiegore Yes they are. $\{x\}$ is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$. It doesn't matter what $x$ is, $\{x\}\in[0,1)$. Does it answer your question? If not , feel free to ask more :)

Comment: Yes.  I see that I completely misunderstood the meaning, and I am considering deleting my answer.  My remaining question is what is $[x]$.

Comment: @cpiegore $[\cdot]$ is same as $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ which is, as you already know, [the floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: Do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: @cpiegore I think you should because the book's intention doesn't match your interpretation and it might create some confusion though I can totally see where you're coming from :)

Answer (score 2):

From
$$(\sqrt{1978}+\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor)(\sqrt{1978}-\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor)=1978-\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor^2$$
one has
$$y=\sqrt{1978}-\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor=\frac{1978-\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor^2}{\sqrt{1978}+\lfloor \sqrt{1978}\rfloor}\lt \frac{1978-\lfloor \sqrt{1936}\rfloor^2}{\sqrt{1978}+\lfloor \sqrt{1936}\rfloor}\lt\frac{1978-1936}{44+44}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$  44^2 - 1978 = -42 < 0 $$
$$  89^2 - 1978 \cdot 2^2 = 9 > 0  $$